# Activist shared printing material gallery

Tags: download, photo-gallery, management, sharing, print

What would you say would be the best way to do this:

We would like to create a section on our activist community FB page and website in order to share with everyone images and files ready for printing panflets, brochures, t-shirts, stickers, etc. Let's say we have some cool slogans for t-shirts, so we would like to show them on a gallery, and offer for download the original design files needed for a print shop to create the t-shirts. And the same thing for all other kinds of media. We want to enable anyone to be able to just download the files for free, and easily create printed materials with them. But besides offering this hybrid between picture gallery and downloads manager, we would also like to make it very easy for anyone to upload and share their own files with the community, to make it a true collaboration initiative, be it that they get posted automatically, or that we first review and approve all uploads.

Cafepress or Spreadshirt let you upload your design and sell your own merchandise. We need something similar, but where people can then download working files for making quality printings and materials.

What apps, tools, services or methods are out there with which you think this could be best done?? We have some ideas, but we would like to hear some more!!

Comment: Questions of the form "What would be the best way..." are generally frowned upon. See the FAQ

Answer (score 1):

I would have text links below the graphic logos in a gallery indicating the file format they can download PDF, EPS, Illustrator etc all print ready. You probably won't be able to build a community in a facebook page. You are better off customizing WordPress so you'll have 100% control over the content. Contact form 7 can be used to let visitors upload files and you can set limits and file type specifications. Once you receive the email just add it to your gallery and upload the print ready files. I don't think you'll find a turn key website that does both, let users upload files, give you control of custom pages to upload and link to downloadable content along with have some sort of community.